# What are these on the F/A-18F's wingtips?

Tags: fighter

At [5:34](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6aAhfyWwNc&feature=youtu.be), former TOPGUN instructor Cdr [E. Vincent Aiello](https://www.linkedin.com/in/evincentaiello) (the narrator) says

> Looks like you've got [I can't decipher] Xes.

1. What words was he speaking?
2. Is he identifying the missile-looking object marked by my red arrow below?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He says:

> Looks like you've got some [AIM 9X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIM-9_Sidewinder)s on the wings

Yes, the AIM 9 ("Sidewinder") is a commonly carried short range air-to-air missile with infrared seeking head, with the 9X being a particular modernized variant.